# How to Post a JavaScript variable to Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, post

Thanks for reading, hopefully my presentation is clear to the reader and aptly shows my lack of understanding. I am very new to node.

I am using node.js with eonasdan datetime.

The problem I need to solve is to print epoch time from console.log in epoch.js from a date sent by a button click in epoch.ejs. Epoch.ejs is viewed in a browser and the html/ejs code easily shows an alert with the epoch in it.

But I am having troubles sending the data back to be printed out from console.log in epoch format (1548694980). I can only print it out in console.log in this format:  01/28/2019 12:03 PM

I do not care if I convert it in the epoch.ejs or in epoch.js.

At present, when I capture the date in the ejs file, and use body-parser to send it to the node epoch.ejs file.

I believe rightly or perhaps wrongly that he format is available within the javascript function. One solution may be to use a global variable and get this into the body. Some attempts have a failed. Described below.

Putting this at the top of the script in the html has caused the datetimepicker to be unable to display the initial date. So making a global variable in javascript has a conflice which I cannot find:

```
 var start = $('#dateTimeStart').data('DateTimePicker').date().unix() 
    alert(start)
```

The node.js code (started with 'node epoch.js'):

```
//setup

var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require('path')

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get("/", function(req, res, next){
      res.render("epoch")
});

app.post("/postDateTimeStart", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.start);
  times(req.body, res);
);

pp.get('/getJson', function (req, res) {
    // If it's not showing up, just use req.body to see what is actually             being passed.
    console.log(req.body.selectpicker);
});

function times(parms, res){ 
//get parms based on input name attribute from html and parse
    var startTime = parms.dateTimeStart;
    var dateStart = parms.start

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end("start time: " + startTime);
    console.log(startTime, dateStart)
}        

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("serving test demo on port 3000")
});
```

The html (ending in ejs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <header>
    <title>Send Epoch to Node Test</title>

    <script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"></link>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#dateTimeStart').datetimepicker({
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
            });

       });

        function getValue() {
            var dTstart = $('#dateTimeStart').data("DateTimePicker").date();
            if( dTstart ){

                /* HOW DO I GET THIS VARIABLE TO BE SEEN BY NODE? */
                alert(dTstart.unix());
            }
        }

       $('#dateTimeStart').datetimepicker();

       var start = $('#dateTimeStart').data('DateTimePicker').date().unix() 
       alert(start)

    </script>

  </header>

  <body>

    <form action="/postDateTimeStart" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Draw</label>
                <p><button onclick="getValue()" type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-block">Graph it!</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for='dateTimeStart'>Start Date-and-Time</label>
            <div class='input-group date' id='dateTimeStart'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" name='dateTimeStart' />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Expected results would be in the console log when clicking the button:

1548695940
01/28/2019 12:19 PM 1548695940

Actual results after clicking the button:

undefined
01/28/2019 12:18 PM undefined

Comment: I'm honestly having trouble figuring out exactly what your question is.  If you're trying to send the value of `dTstart.unix()` to your node server, you could use an Ajax call to send a request to your node server with that value as either a query parameter (if it's a GET request) or in the properly encoded body (if it's a POST request).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Hopefully my edit clarifies. I want to print epoch time in node's console.log from a datetime selected by the user, after a button is clicked. I can print epoch time to the user, but not on the node server via console.log. Thank you for taking the time to provide the helpful comment about clarity. I do not know how I might do this with ajax, I have not used ajax. Can you post code? I'm also seeking to return the user to the same page after clicking the button, would that be affected with the ajax approach?

Comment: No, you don't want an ajax call. You simply want a second `<input type=text name=start>` whose `.value` you should set to the `dTstart.unix()` number before the form is getting submitted.

Comment: On the other hand, yes, you really should edit the `epoch.js`  file to be able to parse the value that you are actually getting. Notice that your page should ideally work without any client-side javascript as well.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm seeking to come up with the correct javascript to accomplish that in addition to your `<input type=text name=start>`. This does not seem to work::  `$("button").click(function(){        $("input:text").val(dTstart);        });`

Comment: Try `input[name=start]` as a selector instead

Comment: @Bergi: oddly this prevents the calendar function from loading the date `$("button").click(function(){
           $("input name=start).val(dTstart);
       });`

Comment: @jfriend00 How might I do this using ajax using a post?.Can you suggest code? I've lost a day on this already and I'm grateful for the insight.

Comment: I can't help because I don't understand what you're really trying to accomplish.  If you just want the value sent with the form, then do like Bergi's suggested and just insert the value in the form before the form is submitted.

Comment: @jfriend00 why the down vote? I tried what he suggested, i provided the code, said it did not work, gave the result and asked for supporting code.  But have not been given sufficient details to resolve my misunderstanding. Nice. I showed my complete code with the expected results. People can easily see what its not doing.

Comment: Thanks @benji. I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the javascript where the alert was previously posted from:

```
if( dTstart ){
    alert(dTstart.unix());
}
```

to:

```
if( dTstart ){
                document.getElementById("dTstart").value = dTstart.unix();
            }
```

and adding this to the last line of the body:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dTstart" name="dTstart" value="">
```

Result as expected:
1548681480 01/28/2019 8:18 AM 1548681480